# Quadrilateral ABCD satisfies $\overline{2AB}=\overline{AC}$, $\overline{BC}=\overline{\sqrt{3}}$, $\overline{BD}=\overline{DC}$ and $<BAC=60$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Quadrilateral ABCD is inscribed in a circle satisfies $\overline{2AB}=\overline{AC}$, $\overline{BC}=\overline{\sqrt{3}}$, $\overline{BD}=\overline{DC}$ and $<BAC=60$

I've never been good at Euclidean geometry questions like this... Really, what strategies could I employ to begin an analysis of the situation? I'm working through a text on Euclidean geometry and this is a question. The specific questions being asked about this scenario are the following:

1). The radius of the circumscribed circle

2). $\overline{AC}$

3). $<BDC$

4). The area of $\Delta BDC$

5). $\overrightarrow{CA} \cdot \overrightarrow{DC}$

Now, The fact that $\overline{BD}=\overline{DC}$ struck me as odd. The length of a diagonal is equal to the length of one of the sides? I want to say that this implies that the quadrilateral we are dealing with must not be convex.

Since $<BAC=60$, we can use the law of cosines to deduce that $\overline{AC}=2$ and so $\overline{AB}=1$.

My analysis sort of hits a road block here. I have not used the fact that the quadrilateral is inscribed in a circle. For a quadrilateral inscribed in a circle, it is well known that:

1. The product of the diagonals of a quadrilateral inscribed in a circle is equal to the sum of the product of its two pairs of opposite sides.

1. The opposite angles of  quadrilateral inscribed in a circle are supplementary. i.e., the sum of the opposite angles is equal to 180˚.

However, I have not been able to make use of these facts.

Can anyone help me out here??  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Draw the diagram of the quadrilateral, with $A$ at $(0,0)$ and $B $ at $(1, 0)$, and point $C$ at $(1, \sqrt{3})$.  Find the center of the circle that passes through $A,B,C$ Place $D$ such that it equidistant from B and C.

Comment: I found that the center of the circle through $A,B,C$ is $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{sqrt{3}}{2}}$. If I place $D$ so that it is equidistant from $B$ and $C$, then are you saying $D$ will also lie on this circle?

Comment: Yes. Since the quadrilateral is cyclic, then $D$ lies on this circle, and at the same time it is equidistant from $B$ an $C$ because $\overline{BD} = \overline{DC}$.  This gives the coordinates of point $D$ immediately.  So now you have the coordinates of all the vertices.

Comment: Surely there are an infinite amount of points that are equidistant from $B$ and $C$. I have to make sure that I pick the coordinate so that D is also on the circle, right? I mean, not every point equidistant from $B$ and $C$ is on the circle. Right?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly.  That's what I mean.  Finding $D$ once you apply the fact that it is on the circumcircle of $A,B,C$ and the fact that it is equidistant from $B$ and $C$ ,  then it should be obvious where $D$ is.  Once you have $D$ coordinates you can answer all the other questions in this problem such as the area of $\triangle BDC$ and $\vec{CA} \cdot \vec{DC} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First note that since $<BAC = 60$ and $2AB = AC$ it tells us $\Delta ABC$ is congruent to the general $30, 60, 90$ triangle (by $SAS$). This tells us that $<ABC = 90$.

    Using the fact that the hypotenuse of an inscribed right triangle is a diameter then we have that $r = \frac{AC}{2}$ but as you stated $AC = 2$ so $r = 1$
2. Correctly by using laws of cosines $AC = 2$
3. Note that we know $<BAC = 60$ and $<BDC$ lies on the same arc as $<BAC$ (arc $BC$) then we know these angle equal so $<BDC = 60$
4. Now we know that $<BDC = 60$ we can see that $\Delta BDC$ is an congruent to the general equilateral triangle (by SAS since $BD = DC$). This now tells us $BD = DC = BC = \sqrt{3}$ so the area of $\Delta BDC = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}sin(60) = \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$
5. We have already worked out that $|CA| = 2$ and $|DC| = \sqrt{3}$. Then since $<ABC = 90$ and $<DBC = 60$ we have that $<ABD = 30$ and therefore since angles in the triangle $\Delta ABX$ (where $X$ the intersection of lines $AC$ and $BD$) is add to $180$, lines BD and AC meet at $90$ degrees. Hence $\Delta BCX$ is congruent to $\Delta DCX$ (by $AAS$) which tells us that the angle between $CA$ and $DC$ is equal to $<ACB = 30$. Hence the dot product of $CA$ and $DC$ is $-2\sqrt{3}\cos{30} = -3$

If you want a short extension then show that quadrilateral $ABCD$ is a kite

Comment: Regarding your side note: By law of cosines I meant $c^2=a^2+b^2-2abcos(\gamma)$, which I believe does not require $\Delta ABC$ to be a right triangle.

Comment: In that case ignore what i said

Comment: Also, regarding $(5)$, we want the dot product of the two vectors $DC$ and $CA$. I'm about to go for a bit but I'll come back and read your answer carefully soon and probably end up giving you a green check mark haha!

Comment: Oh I'll correct that then

Comment: Oh I see I stated the question (5) wrong.. My fault.. I'll fix it in my question. Thanks again man great answer

Comment: Can you expand on your step #3? How does the fact that the angles are on the same arc impliy that the angles are the same??? Is this a well known theorem? I can't find it on google :P

Comment: Its just a circle theorem. Google "angles subtended by the same arc at the circumference equal" and i think you'll find something

Comment: Oooh right! duh. Thanks man

Comment: From (5): Hence $\Delta BCX$ is congruent to $\Delta DCX$ (by $AAS$) which tells us that the angle between $CA$ and $DC$ is equal to $<ACB = 30$.

Is it possible that we see that the angle between $CA$ and $DC$ is 30 by noting that $<CXD=<BXA=90$ and since we know $<CDB=60$ we can conclude that $<DCA=<DCX=30$

Comment: I'm not seeing why the dot product of $CA$ and $DC$ is negative

Comment: the vectors were moving in opposite directions (it should technically be $\cos{150}$)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = \overline{AB}$ , then $\overline{AC} = 2 x$, and we are given that $\overline{BC} = \sqrt{3} $ and that $\angle BAC = 60^\circ$

Applying the law of cosines to $\triangle ABC$, we get

$ (\sqrt{3})^2 = x^2 + (2 x)^2 - 2 x (2 x) (\frac{1}{2}) $

Hence,

$ 3 = x^2 + 4 x^2 - 2 x^2 = 3 x^2 $

From which, $x = 1$.  Therefore, $\overline{AB} = 1 $ and $\overline{AC} = 2 $

Now using coordinate geometry, we can set vertex $A = (0,0)$ and $B = (1, 0)$, then $C = (1, \sqrt{3}) $ (Assuming $C$ is in the upper half plane).

Next, we find the circle on which $A,B,C$ lies.  The center is the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, which is the line $x = \dfrac{1}{2}$, and the perpendicular bisector of $BC$, which is the line $ y = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $

Hence the center of the circumcircle of $\triangle$ ABC is $O = (\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ) $

The radius of this circumcircle is $R = \overline{OA} = 1 $

Since point $D$ lies on the cicrcumcircle and on perpendicular bisector of $BC$ (because it is equidistant from $B$ and $C$), then we $D$ can be

$D_1 = O + (-R, 0) = (-\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ) \hspace{25pt} (1)$

or

$D_2 = O + (R, 0) = ( \dfrac{3}{2} , \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ) \hspace{25pt} (2)$

However, from the cyclic order of the vertices, $D_2$ is rejected.  Hence $D = D_1 $.

Now we can compute the area.

The area of $ABCD = [ABC] + [ACD_1] = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt{3} + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \sqrt{3} (- \dfrac{1}{2} ) \right) = \sqrt{3} $

Also, we have $\vec{CA} = A - C = (-1, -\sqrt{3} ) $, and $\vec{DC} = C - D = ( \dfrac{3}{2} , \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ) $

So $\vec{CA} \cdot \vec{DC} = - \dfrac{3}{2} - \dfrac{3}{2} = -3 $

Comment: Oh man!!! Great proof thanks so much

Comment: Can you explain to me how you calculate the area of $ABCD$? Where did you get the equality $[ABC]+[ACD_1]=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{3}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\sqrt{3}(\frac{-1}{2}}$

Comment: I split the quadrilateral $ABCD$ into $\triangle ABC $ and $\triangle ACD$.  The area of a triangle is given by $ [ABC] = \frac{1}{2} | (B_x - A_x) (C_y - A_y) - (B_y - A_y)(C_x - A_x) | \\$ and similarly for $\triangle ACD$